# Excel 2016 Pivot Table

Tags: pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to create a third column that shows the percentage of Sold from the total of Lost & Sold.  How do I go about this, please?

```
Lost Sold
222 169
191 139
31  30
209 124
138 61
71  63
547 392
187 157
53  24
307 211
978 685
```

Answer (score 0):

First sum sold and lost values as ...  total of Lost & Sold
then calculate the percentage of Sold sold/total of Lost & Sold [The answer is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NzBC.png)